# How to access a /media folder that has been mounted from a external hardrive?

Tags: mount, permissions, apache2

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 x64. 
I have installed Apache, php5.

I have configured two sites folders in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`
One is the in `/home/me/www` and the other is on the external disk let's say `/media/me/www`.

I think the problem is that `/media` is owned by `root` and all files had restrictive permissions, so I can only see my files in my computer, or with sftp or samba, login with my username.

What I want is to view those files in apache from another computer, but the server always gave me the `403 Forbidden` message.

I was thinking of changing the owner of the media folder, and to change the files permissions. Or I found I could mount the drive in another path, but that would be more problematic because I already have some apps using that path.

My question what do I have to do to allow access to apache to show the media folder?

The hard drive is NTFS format.
Also I'm not an expert in linux, but knows the basics.

Comment: I would suggest changing the mount point and then create a symbolic link at the old location to point to the new one - so you won't need to change the path in programs that point to it since they will follow the link.

Answer (score 0):

> media folder that has been mounted is itself is in root directory as
>   home.

```
1. / – Root
2. /bin – User Binaries
3. /sbin – System Binaries
4. /etc – Configuration Files
5. /dev – Device Files
6. /proc – Process Information
7. /var – Variable Files
8. /tmp – Temporary Files
9. /usr – User Programs
10. /home – Home Directories
11. /boot – Boot Loader Files
12. /lib – System Libraries
13. /opt – Optional add-on Applications
14. /mnt – Mount Directory
15. /media – Removable Media Devices
16. /srv – Service Data
```

> It's like:
>
> `/home/testfile`.
>   `/media/testfile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your Apache user to the `vboxfs` group if you use VirtualBox.

```
usermod -aG vboxfs your_apache_user_name
```